# Градиент с повторением и наклоном

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать такой градиент фоновый у блока? Пробовал, но получается размытый с плавным переходом.

Answer (score 4):

Для получения чётких границ укажите точные координаты начала и окончания соответствующего цвета:

```css
.grad {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 115deg, green 60px, green 120px, tomato 121px, tomato 180px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grad"></div>
```